# Can the APPDATA environment variable ever be missing on Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm making a program that stores configuration options in an `%APPDATA%` folder on Windows, and I'm wondering how pedantic I need to be about error handling for this part. Notably, is there every a case where the `%APPDATA%` variable can be missing, and is there anything I can do as a fallback in case it does mysteriously disappear?

Comment: It will never be missing.

Comment: A user can explicitly delete it: `set APPDATA=`.

Comment: Ah, good to know! That means I do need to check if it exists then. If you want to write up a small answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Your program could be run with a custom environment via `CreateProcessW` -- or as a descendant of such a program. Or, similarly, an unrelated environment if `CreateProcessAsUserW` is called without loading the profile and getting the environment via `LoadUserProfileW` and `CreateEnvironmentBlock`. If possible, the shell API (e.g. [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)) should always be preferred over relying on environment variables.